# Работа с классами и видимостью элементов

Tags: css, vue.js

Можно ли каким то образом скрывать дочерний элемент если у родителя есть определенный класс?

Answer (score 0):

У родителя есть массив классов `parentClass`, если массив содержит класс hideChildClass, то ребенок не отображается(реализовано через v-if)

В данном случае экземпляр Vue является родителем, но если это будет компонент, то все тоже будет работать.

```js
const child = {
  template: '<div class="child">Я ребенок</div>'
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { child },
  data: () => {
    const hideChildClass = 'hide-child'
    return {
      hideChildClass,
      parentClass: [hideChildClass, 'parent-class']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle () {
      if (this.parentClass.includes(this.hideChildClass))
        this.parentClass = this.parentClass.filter(i => i !== this.hideChildClass)
      else
        this.parentClass.push(this.hideChildClass)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.parent-class {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div :class="parentClass">
    Я родитель, мои классы: {{ parentClass }}<br>
    <child v-if="!parentClass.includes(hideChildClass)"></child>
    <button @click="toggle">Переключить класс</button>
  </div>
</div>
```